# Passing Microsoft Scripting Runtime dictionary from VBA to C# using Excel DNA

Tags: c#, vba, excel, excel-dna

I am very new to C# and to Excel DNA. I currently have a some data stored in a Microsoft Scripting Runtime dictionary that I want to pass to some method that I have written in C#. Ive created a simple method in C# (called FetchDictionary) to take the dictionary as input and returning a integer back to VBA but I get an error saying that:
"Cannot run the macro 'FetchDictionary'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled"
When I try to call other functions where I am just passing a double array for example I do not encounter this problem.
I have added a reference to my C# to

Below are both the VBA and the C# functions

VBA:

```
Sub test()
    Dim test As New Dictionary
    Dim check As Integer
    test.Add "1", 1

    check = Application.Run("FetchDictionary", test)
End Sub
```

C#:

```
    public static int FetchDictionary(Scripting.Dictionary Dict)
    {
        int check = Dict.get_Item("1");
        return check;
    }
```

I  would really appreciate anybody's help
Thanks

Comment: Thank Dy.Lee. I still get the error. It seem that the dictionary type is the problem...

Comment: Thanks Anurag for editing the post :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `FetchDictionary` function won't be registered by Excel-DNA as a function in Excel, since the `Scripting.Dictionary` parameter type is not one of the types supported by Excel for user-defined functions. So Excel doesn't know anything about `FetchDictionary`, hence the error you get.

Also, the `Application.Run` call won't understand COM objects like the `Scripting.Dictionary`, so will fail even if it could get `FetchDictionary` registered. You're limited to types that Excel will understand and can pass to registered UDF functions through the Excel C API. From VBA this means primitive types like `Double` and `String` and for anything more complicated you'd use a `Variant` array.

The primary use case for Excel-DNA is to make worksheet UDF functions using .NET. However, there is also some help in adding classes to your add-in that can be referenced from VBA. To make an Excel-DNA add-in with some classes that can the called from VBA you can follow these instructions:

- http://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.co.za/2014/03/interfacing-c-and-vba-with-exceldna-no.html
- http://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.co.za/2014/03/interfacing-c-and-vba-with-exceldna_16.html